# fixing rewrite mod to work well with get

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to modify a htaccess file so that it will give a nice url for a search form.

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ look.php?q=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule ^search/?q=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ look.php?q=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule ^search/?q=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ look.php?s=$1&q=$2 [nc]
```

If the search button is click the url returns `/search/?q=tom` -- returns nothing

if i enter `/search/tom` in the url -- it returns result that matchs tom

If the search button is click the url returns `/search/?q=tom+jerry` -- return no result which is wrong because if i do `look.php?s=tom+jerry` it returns the correct result..

my aim is this `/search/?q=tom`  or  `/search/?q=tom+jerry`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to match the query string - it won't be matched in the RewriteRule.

So you would replace your second rule by something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^search/ look.php?q=%1 [L,NC]
```

And I don't understand your third rule so I'm not going to try to fix it.

Comment: What would the URL look like?